How to create a multiple database configuration for Spring Boot while sharing Oracle UCP and Hibernate properties?
I have two data sources, source alpha and source omega. I want to be able to create the configuration for each data source but keep the rest of the properties shared between them, like the following:
spring.datasource.type=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-factory-class-name=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.oracleucp.sql-for-validate-connection=select * from dual
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-pool-name=CustomConnectionPool
spring.datasource.oracleucp.max-pool-size=16
spring.jdbc.template.fetch-size=647
spring.jdbc.template.max=647

This is what I have so far with a simple driver data source:
spring.alpha.datasource.username=alphauser
spring.alpha.datasource.password=alphapass
spring.alpha.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@alpha.com:80085/ALPHA5
spring.alpha.datasource.type=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource

spring.omega.datasource.username=omegauser
spring.omega.datasource.password=omegapass
spring.omega.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@omega.com:80085/OMEGA10
spring.omega.datasource.type=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource

This is what the alpha looks like:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    considerNestedRepositories      = true,
    repositoryImplementationPostfix = "Implementation",
    basePackages                    = "com.so.multipledb.dao.alpha",
    entityManagerFactoryRef         = "alphaEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef           = "alphaTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceAlphaAutoConfiguration {
    private final Environment env;

    public PersistenceAlphaAutoConfiguration(Environment env) {
        super();
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.alpha")
    public DataSource alphaDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean alphaEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(alphaDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.so.multipledb.model.alpha");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager alphaTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(alphaEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    considerNestedRepositories      = true,
    repositoryImplementationPostfix = "Implementation",
    basePackages                    = "com.so.multipledb.dao.omega",
    entityManagerFactoryRef         = "omegaEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef           = "omegaTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceOmegaAutoConfiguration {
    private final Environment env;

    public PersistenceOmegaAutoConfiguration(Environment env) {
        super();
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.omega")
    public DataSource omegaDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean omegaEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(omegaDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.so.multipledb.model.omega");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager omegaTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(omegaEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}

I'm supposed to use something like PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource() or OracleDataSource. As you can see, not only are the properties being repeated in the java file itself for hibernate, but the type is also repeated in the properties.
